# How do conjugation rules apply for vectors in complex spaces? So I have (1,0,0),(1,2,0),(1,2,3)

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Inner product is defined to be $x_1$ * conjugate of $x_2$ + $y_1$ *conjugate of $y_2$ +$z_1$ *conjugate of $z_2$
Is the inner product of (1,0,0)(1,2,0), 1*1 or 1*-1?

Also I have the complex vector space with span ((1,1,0,0),(1,1,1+i,1+i),(1 + i,1+i,i,i),(1,1,1,1)). I know that they are LI since the only combination that gives the zero vector is having 0's in front of all vectors. Since it has 4 vectors, I thought it would have dimension 4. The answer is 2, is that because we are looking over the complex vector spaces and therefore the 1st and 4th vectors do not count?

Comment: They're not linearly independent. Even the subset $\{(1,1,0,0),(1,1,1+i,1+i),(1,1,1,1)\}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: OK I will re try it, but for part 1 of the question, how would inner product be defined. It is positive 1 or negative 1?

Comment: Positive. You only negate the imaginary part.

Comment: Thanks. Also, how do I find the polar decomposition of the 2 by 2 matrix with  (1,1) in row 1, and (0,1) in row 2.